# Http Request with multiple content type and xml

Tags: c#, http, xmlhttprequest, http-post, content-type

I have a 2 questions about how should I implement the Http Request in C# with multiple content type, and also the request needs to include the content of a xmk file. The request should be like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=----xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
//some content here

Content-Type: application/xml
//some content here

//The content of XML file

Content-Type: text/plain
//some content here
```

How should I implement with these 3 content-types in one single HTTP Post Request in C#? Thank you so much.

Comment: You make the content type XML and then you stick the various return values into an XML doc which is your only return value